# What is the best EXIT status check Command that works in Rubocop, Linux and Windows servers?

Tags: pipeline, exit-code, rubocop

I've been trying to make my pipeline (following rubocop syntax) and Linux/ Windows machines happy but for some reason I am stuck in the exit status checking. It is causing problem.

I have used the following and the below results:

`$?.exitstatus` - **NOT OK** in rubocop (syntax concerns); OK in Linux; OK in Windows

`system()` - OK in rubocop; OK in Linux; **NOT OK** in Windows (it is `not recognized as an internal or external command`)

`$CHILD_STATUS.exitstatus` - OK in rubocop; **NOT OK** in Linux (it needs `require 'English'` library); OK in Windows

I don't want to install anything in the machines. Any best way to make it all OK?

Thank you.

Comment: What's the issue with `require 'English'`?

Comment: hi @Marc-AndréLafortune it's causing error cannot find 'english' library in the linux OS since there's no existing English library in linux unlike windows.

Comment: My guess is you need to `require 'English'`, with uppercase 'E', because your Linux OS is probably case-sensitive?

Comment: yes thanks @Marc-AndréLafortune

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted way is:

```rb
require 'English'  # Capital 'E'!

$CHILD_STATUS.exitstatus
```

Note that the `English` lib is a standard lib that comes bundled with all versions of Ruby

Comment: The capital 'E' in English solves the problem. Now I can use it in my Linux servers too. Thanks!